# List of figure and tables newline after each chapter/section

Tags: table-of-contents

i got a list of figures and tables but there is newline after each chapter/section.

Is it possible to disable that?

I want this:

Abbildung 1.1
Abbildung 2.1
Abbildung 2.2

I use the documentclass scrreprt if this is helpful.

[image]

```
    \documentclass
[   oneside,       
    fontsize=12pt,      
    %DIV=15,            
    %BCOR=17mm,          
    headsepline,      
    %footsepline,       
    open=right,          
    paper=a4,            
    abstract=false,     
    listof=totoc,        
    bibliography=totoc,  
    titlepage,           
    headinclude=true,    
    footinclude=false,   
    numbers=noenddot     
]   {scrreprt}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have helped to provide a complete MWE. I had to waste time preparing one.

Try this:

```
% loftabprob.tex  SE 651779

\documentclass{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

% no extra chapter space in LoF and LoT
\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\endgroup

\chapter{First}
\begin{figure}
  A FIGURE
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Second}
\begin{figure}
  AN ILLUSTRATION
  \caption{Another figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If this helps you please acknowledge it.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what i was searching for.